# swift OutputStream could not find member "write"

Tags: ios, swift, nsstream, external-accessory, nsoutputstream

I'm trying for a while to send data to an OutputStream to communicate with another device. (For this i use the External Accessory Framework) But the function does not work. I have the error    Could not find member "write". I hope somebody can help me to find the solution. thank you.

```
func _writeData() {

    while (_session.outputStream.hasSpaceAvailable && _write.length > 0) {
    var bytesWritten: Int = _session?.outputStream.write(_write.bytes, _write.length);
        if(bytesWritten == -1){
            println("write error");
            break;
        }
        else if (bytesWritten > 0){
            _write.replaceBytesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, bytesWritten), withBytes: nil, length: 0);
        }
    }
}

//high level write data method
func writeData(data: NSData) {
    if(_write == nil) {
        _write = NSMutableData.alloc();
    }
    _write.appendData(data);
    self._writeData();
}
```

The Error -------->  var bytesWritten: Int = _session?.outputStream.write(_write.bytes, _write.length);

There are the function where i open and close the session

//open a session with the accessory and set up the input and output stream on the default run loop
    func openSession(accessory: EAAccessory, withProtocolString protocolString: String) -> ObjCBool{

```
    _session = EASession(accessory: accessory, forProtocol: protocolString);

    if(_session != nil) {

        _session.inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode);
        _session.inputStream.open()

        _session.outputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode);
        _session.outputStream.open();

    } else {
        println("Creating session failed");
    }
    return (_session != nil);
}

//close the session with the accessory
func closeSession() {

    _session.inputStream.close();
    _session.inputStream.removeFromRunLoop(NSRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode);

    _session.outputStream.close();
    _session.outputStream.removeFromRunLoop(NSRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't start your functions with '_' it's used eslewhere in Swift - if your intention is to mark the the function as Private as of beta 4 that's possible with i.e. private func yourFunction(). Also I wouldn't put _ in front of variable names ;)

Answer (score 2):

after testing many things, I have been able to write to the socket, here is my code:

```
    var inputStream: NSInputStream?
    var outputStream: NSOutputStream?

    NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName("localhost", port: 8443, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
    outputStream?.open()
    inputStream?.open()
    //while(true){
      //get input
    //}
    let data: NSData = "this is a test string".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    outputStream?.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
```

you can test it using net cat

```
nc -l 8443
```